# Prove $f(x)\geq e^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, such that $f^{\ '}\geq f$ and $f(0)=1.$ Prove $f(x)\geq e^x, \forall x\geq0$.

So I started by defining a function $g(x)=f(x)-e^x$, and my intuition tells me that $f^{\ '}\geq f$ means $f$ is increasing, but I'm not sure how to continue.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I was thinking about this , please correct me if I am wrong - i proceed through contradiction suppose $f(x) < e^{x}$ , then $f(0) < 1$ but $f(0) = 1$ , hence a contradiction thus $f(x) \geq e^{x}$, but here i never used the fact of $f^{'} \geq f$ ?.

Comment: Baymax, your idea is wrong, as you have to prove that for all $x\ge 0, f \ge e^x$.

Comment: Still i don't get why am I wrong @Lelouch

Comment: @BAYMAX The negation of $\forall x,\ f(x)\geq e^{x}$ is **not** $\forall x,\ f(x) < e^{x}$; but your contradiction relies on the latter.

Comment: Baymax, you assumed that FOR ALL x\ge 0, f(x) \le e^x, and then made a contradiction. This shows that for NOT ALL x\ge 0, f(x) \le e^x. But you have to prove that FOR ALL x, f(x) is \ge e^x. Think carefully. You will understand.

Comment: I think negation is $\exists x < 0 s.t f(x) < e^{x}$  is it correct @ClementC.so I cannot take $x =0 $

Comment: Yes, and this is not what you relied on, making your proposed proof flawed. You have no guarantee at all that $f(0)<1$, when proceeding by contradiction.

Comment: "this is not what you relied on" ? @ClementC.

Comment: (What you wrote in your comment, after editing, basically. You initially relied on taking $x=0$ in the contradiction; and indeed, you cannot, as you realized.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the proof is the transformation

$$f'(x)\ge f(x)\implies f'(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x}\ge 0\implies(f(x)e^{-x})'\ge 0.$$

Then $f(x)e^{-x}$ is a non-decreasing function such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)e^{-x}\ge1$ for positive $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)e^{-x}$,note that $g$ is increasing and $g(0)=1$ hence $f(x) \geq e^x$ **QED**

Comment: Your proof is good, but this dosen't accurately answer the OP's question regarding his approach. +1for the proof anyway

Comment: How do you know that $g$ is increasing ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Differentiating, as in the accepted answer to the nigh-identical duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129435/if-fx-is-continuous-and-differentiable-function-prove-that-fx-geq-e3 , I reckon.

Comment: @ClementC.: I guess that the answerer should explain that.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, surely. I'm with you on that.

Comment: Dear @YvesDaoust: That was left for OP to figure out.Regards,

Comment: @ArpitKansal: sorry, I beat you out.

Comment: Dear @YvesDaoust: Yeah thats fine,cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I have a semi formal proof to help you along your line of thought.

Let $g(x) = f(x) - e^x$ (as you defined.

Then $g'(x) = f'(x) - e^x$

Clearly $\forall x\ge 0, g'(x) \ge g(x)$ since $f' \ge f$.

Let us look at the zeroes of $g(x)$. Let $a$ be a zero. That is

$g(a) = 0, a\gt 0$ (if there exists no such a, then our proof is already done - justify yourself why)

Then,$g'(a) \ge 0$ but, we know that $g(x)$ is positive in the neighbourhood of x = 0(again justify why)

So, for $g(x)$ to be negative in the neighbourhood of $a$, the derivative must be negative(justify why). But clearly,that is not so. You can also justify from the last inequality that at all further roots, the derivative is only zero at those point(touchig the axis). Hence your proof is done, as $g(x)$ is non negative. Hope this helped.